# Equality validation in vector calculus

Tags: calculus

I have getting myself into the area of fluid mechanics.

I would like to know if the following relationship holds.

$\left (\vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \nabla  \right ) \vec{\mathbf{b}} = \vec{\mathbf{a}} \cdot \nabla \vec{\mathbf{b}}$

The left side of the equation is also known as the convective operator (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvectiveOperator.html).

Reading:

(vector $\vec{\mathbf{a}}$ dot product with the $\nabla$ operator) times vector $\vec{\mathbf{b}}$ is equal to the dot product of vector $\vec{\mathbf{a}}$ and the gradient of vector $\vec{\mathbf{b}}$.

Sorry if this a very basic question!

Comment: No, it does not hold. The convective operator gives a vector, while the RHS is a scalar.

Comment: RHS is also a vector, along $\vec a$

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same. Let's look at the $\hat x$ component for example in Cartesian coordinates. The left hand side (from the link that you have) is $$a_x\frac{\partial b_x}{\partial x}+a_y\frac{\partial b_x}{\partial y}+a_z\frac{\partial b_x}{\partial_z}$$
For the right hand side, $$\nabla\vec b=\frac{\partial b_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial b_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial b_z}{\partial_z}$$
This is a scalar. So when we multiply with vector $\vec a$, the $\hat x$ component will be $$a_x\frac{\partial b_x}{\partial x}+a_x\frac{\partial b_y}{\partial y}+a_x\frac{\partial b_z}{\partial_z}$$
Notice the difference: in the right hand side you have each term of the sum multiplied with a different component of $\vec a$, but each derivative acts on $b_x$. On the right hand side each term contains the same $a_x$, but the derivatives act on different components of $\vec b$.

Comment: Your second equality seems false. it is not divergence.

Comment: The gradient of a vector should be a 2nd order tensor. Something like this (https://www.continuummechanics.org/velocitygradient.html)

Comment: @ManuelOliveira Is he talking about the gradient or divergence? Divergence of a vector is a scalar